# Xcode copy/paste an element and losing storyboard view

Tags: copy, storyboard, paste

When I copy and paste an element in the storyboard as soon as I press command-v (paste) I am navigated away from the storyboard and I have to navigate back each and every time. I am not sure what it happening but any help would be appreciated. Did searches through google but all responses seemed to be either deleted or the site not there. Thanks again.